# copy a file 10 times in jMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In order to copy an xml-file for my jMeter-test I created this groovy-script within a loop-controller named `LC`

```
number = (vars.get("__jm__LC__idx") as int) + 1; // get the current iteration and add 1
target = vars.get("fileName") + number;
cp(vars.get("fileName"), target);
```

`fileName` is an env-variable passed to my test as `C:/MyDir/Verkehr.xml`.

However when executing that test I get the following error:

> Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.cp() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [C:/MyDir/Verkehr.xml, C:/MyDir/Verkehr.xml41]
> Possible solutions: any(), grep(), dump(), get(java.lang.String), put(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object)

What I want is `Verkehr.xml1` (actually `Verkehr1.xml` but that leads too far for this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `cp` is, if it's some custom function make sure that the class providing this function is in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

If you don't have this `cp` implementation - the easiest way would be going for [FileUtils.copyFile() function](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) like:

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(new File(vars.get("fileName")), new File(vars.get("fileName") + number))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: haha, I thought the linux-`gp`-function is identical in groovy.